# "invalid enumerant" after glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl

I am running some tutorials on OpenGL. I started with [Durian](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-2.3%3a-Rendering.html) tutorial in C and it works fine. I want to port it to Java + JOGL (I will develop for Android, so I want to learn OpenGL under Java), and I get an error when setting up textures.

The code is:

```
final int[] gl_textures = new int[1];
gl.glGenTextures(1, gl_textures, 0);
int gl_texture = gl_textures[0];

gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_texture );
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,     GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,     GL2.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// no error before this
gl.glTexImage2D( gl_texture,
    0,
    GL2.GL_RGB8,
    image.getWidth(),
    image.getHeight(),
    0,
    GL2.GL_BGR,
    GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    image.getPixelBuffer()
);
// invalid enumerant here
```

Any clue what can be wrong?

I work OpenGL 2.1 (I know, old, but good to learn OpenGL ES). As I said, C tutorial code works fine.

**Edit**

Here is the code for rendering. Full version [can be found here](http://www.pastebay.net/311787)

```
private void render( GLAutoDrawable drawable ) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glUseProgram(m_program);
    gl.glUniform1f( m_uniform_fade_factor, (float)(0.5) );

    gl.glActiveTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glBindTexture( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[0] );
    gl.glUniform1i( m_uniform_textures[0], 0);

    gl.glActiveTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE1);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[1] );
    gl.glUniform1i( m_uniform_textures[1], 1 );

    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertex_buffer );
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(
            m_attribute_position,
            2,
            GL2.GL_FLOAT,
            false,
            sizeof_float * 2,
            0
            );
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray( m_attribute_position );

    gl.glBindBuffer( GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_element_buffer );
    gl.glDrawElements(
            GL2.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,
            4,
            GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
            0);
    gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray( m_attribute_position );

    gl.glFlush();

    drawable.swapBuffers();

    checkGLError(gl);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of the `glTexImage2D` call is wrong. There you put the target, not the texture name. You must set it to `GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

Comment: Thanks, simple mistake. Still, nothing displayed in he screen :(

Comment: @datenwolf: here you go! Hope you can help. I tried both with and without `swapBuffers` and `glFlush`